# Android app works fine on web and on device through PhoneGap Desktop, but is just white screen on build.phonegap.com

Tags: android, cordova, screen

This is my first time using build.phonegap.com.  I have built an app that is entirely self-contained and doesn't use any connection or camera  etc.  It uses jquery, jquery mobile, HTML and CSS.  It is a simple quiz that simply navigates through the DOM to verify the user input.

Here's what I do:

I use PhoneGap Desktop (on Windows) to generate the project and then add the code afterwards.  I test it on my browser, then I test it on my device (Android) through Phonegap Desktop and then I zip up the folder (the project folder that was originally generated by phonegap desktop) and upload it to build.phonegap.com.

1. When I run it through the browser it works perfectly, with no error in the console.
2. When I run it though my device via PhoneGap Desktop, again, it runs perfectly.
3. When I upload it to build.phonegap.com, all seems to be fine (no issues in the debugger either).  I run it my Android device via the QR-code-download and it installs with no issues.
4. **When I open the app via build.phonegap.com, I just get a blank white screen.**

I have checked my config.xml file and all the images and references are correct.  All js and css files are referenced correctly (I've checked and it all works on my device via PhoneGap desktop and on my browser).

There are no js errors in the Chrome console.

I have feeling that I'm missing out something important. I haven't developed an app for a while a lot of the advice and tutorials seem to be out-of-phase with my project.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks,

Joe

Comment: If you're using chrome, have you looked at the web console? I believe pressing the F12 key and going to the console tab is how you get to it. Check it for any errors. (For Firefox, it's right click on page -> inspect element -> console)

Comment: Thanks for your response Pablo.  There are no errors in the console.

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect that.  Thanks again.

Comment: do you think perhaps the problem might lie in the zipping and uploading of your project? EDIT: if it allows uploading files individually, perhaps try that as well. It's possible that zipping it is messing around with spacing or something of the sort which may be leading to an issue.

Comment: OK.  I've checked the PhoneGap Build support and it states that the config and index files both have to be at the root, and you only have to upload the www folder.  So I've moved the config (and I've edited the paths in the config file accordingly) into the www folder (PhoneGap desktop annoyingly has it outside) and zipped up the www folder (as per the PhoneGap Build instructions) and uploaded that... still, exactly the same issue...

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the directory structure and files for the project when it works and on build when it doesn't?

Comment: Pablo - you were barking up the right tree: i had an extra folder in my root which was causing the issues.  A quick restructuring and it started to work.  Thanks!